# Bulk download Europe PMC Metadata

Tags: r, ftp, europepmc

I am trying to download entire metadata from Europe PMC dataset.  I am able to download the metadata through rest api provided by the site. But the constraint is the volume of the data and because of that I am facing some performance issues.

Recently i have downloaded around 20,000 records with 47000 variables.
Europe PMC has approx 31 million such records.

Is there any way I can download Europe PMC dataset using FTP or any more effcient way?
FTP download for metadata is available for only open access articles as of now

Answer (score 2):

You can download the metadata of all full text articles on Europe PMC via FTP.

You can find all of the FTP downloads available here: https://europepmc.org/downloads

The one that contains the metadata is 'Metadata of all Full-Text Europe PMC articles' and the FTP is here: https://europepmc.org/ftp/pmclitemetadata/

Then you could use a flag like [HAS_FT:N](https://www.ebi.ac.uk/europepmc/webservices/rest/search?query=HAS_FT:N) to access the metadata for all other articles via the API. It's still a lot of articles, though.